# How do you instantiate a SPWeb Object from a console app?

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I am trying to write a console app that simply lists the number of lists at the sharepoint root.

I tried doing it by using the following code, but the object SPContext.Current is null.  Any ideas of how to get the web object?

```
 SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("http://localhost") ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://myurl");
SPWeb spMySite = spSite.Allwebs["mysite"];
SPWeb spRootsite = spsite.RootWeb;
```

The console app will only run on the server as usual.
Also, the url used http://myurl can be a url to a page and an SPSite object will be created. E.g. http://myurl/mysite/pages/default.aspx will get a valid SPSite object.

Comment: Just make sure you take into account what Nico stated, SPSite and SPWeb both implement IDisposable and you really need to dispose of then when you're done. http://blogs.msdn.com/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx for more on that

Comment: Yeah, nothing like leaving 2MB objects just lying around.

Comment: Thanks again for this response.  I came back to this again today for reference.

Answer (score 9):

Just adding a little thing to Nat's post:
Even if it's not a important as in a SharePoint WebApp, it's still recommenced to dispose all SPWeb and SPSite objets.
So do keep good habits:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(weburl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        // bla bla
    }
}
```

Note: you can directly pass the weburl to SPSite constructor, so OpenWeb will open the given web.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of other ways you can use SPSite.OpenWeb() as well...

If you keep track of the SPWeb object's GUID:

```
site.OpenWeb(webUid);
```

Using a web's server or site relative URL or title, see [MSDN SPSite.OpenWeb(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474633.aspx) for more details:

```
site.OpenWeb(relativeUrl);
site.OpenWeb(title);
```

Using the precise relative URL and avoiding any clever stuff that SPSite.OpenWeb(string) uses:

```
site.OpenWeb(relativeUrl, true);
```